# Running Django using python3 in Fedora

Tags: django

I have two versions of python installed in my fedora system. I installed django through pip command utility. Now to confirm my django installation through python3 using the following command

```
import django
print(django.get-version())
```

It is giving the message `django not  found`.

But when I run it using the python2.7 shell it verifies that django has been installed. I want to run django using python3 what changes should I make?

Comment: A virtual environment would be extremely useful here...

Comment: How is that to be created

Comment: Try `pip3 install django`

Comment: When i run pip3, it shows the command is not found. I do have python 3.5 installed.

Comment: You need to install pip for python3.

Comment: Pip for python3 is already installed. When i  invoke pip it runs the version for python 2.7